# Woocommerce: Hide payment rates when specific shipping option is selected

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce instance where there are 3 different payment options and 9 different sets of shipping rates - 3 zones, each with 3 different rates.

1 of the rates in each zone should allow only 1 payment gateway to show, but so far I can only get the gateway to hide for every shipping method or none of them.

2 of the shipping rates are different table rates, so I had hoped I could use the 'table_rate:##' in a function to hide shipping rates.

The code I have tried so far is as below. It is only meant to remove the winbnk shipping option if the selected shipping rate is the table rate with the id 54, but it removes the gateway regardless of the selected shipping method.

I've made a schoolboy error or misunderstood something around the shipping methods functionality.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways','remove_payment_gateway_by_shipping_option');

function remove_payment_gateway_by_shipping_option($available_gateways){
global $woocommerce;
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];

if($chosen_shipping = 'table_rate:54'){
    unset( $available_gateways['winbnk'] );

 }    
    return $available_gateways;
}
```

The solution below worked for me, hopefully it is of use to someone else.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'shipping_disables_payment_gateway' );

function shipping_disables_payment_gateway( $available_gateways ) {
global $woocommerce;
$chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
$chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];
    if ( isset( $available_gateways['winbnk'] ) && 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'table_rate:54' ) ) {
unset( $available_gateways['winbnk'] );
}    
return $available_gateways;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have chosen specific option with specific title, the payment option for paypal will be removed. you can use this code,

```html
function alter_shipping_methods($list){
    $chosen_titles = array();
    $available_methods = WC()->shipping->get_packages();
    $chosen_rates = ( isset( WC()->session ) ) ? WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ) : array();
 
    foreach ($available_methods as $method)
           foreach ($chosen_rates as $chosen) {
                if( isset( $method['rates'][$chosen] ) ) $chosen_titles[] = $method['rates'][ $chosen ]->label;
            }
 
    if( in_array( 'Home Delivery', $chosen_titles ) ) {
        $array_diff = array('WC_Gateway_Paypal');
        $list = array_diff( $list, $array_diff );
    }
    return $list;
}
add_action('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'alter_shipping_methods');
```

You can get more details about same topic, Go through the link: http://www.bolderelements.net/support/knowledgebase/hide-payment-gateway-based-on-shipping-option-selected/

Comment: That didn't work, but I have found a solution that does, have revised above.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer. Hopefully it helps someone else.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'shipping_disables_payment_gateway' );

function shipping_disables_payment_gateway( $available_gateways ) {
global $woocommerce;
$chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
$chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];
    if ( isset( $available_gateways['winbnk'] ) && 0 === strpos( $chosen_shipping, 'table_rate:54' ) ) {
unset( $available_gateways['winbnk'] );
}
return $available_gateways;
}
```